# I need some advice on how to format my ints and doubles into a string for sprintf in C. I pasted my code below and some more details

Tags: c

I need help formatting my ints and doubles into a string type for sprintf in the organizeStyle function. You know how if you are using an int, but need it to be a double, you would normally just say something like:

```
int x = 5;
double y;
y = (double) x;
```

Well I need something similar to convert ints and doubles into strings in my code below for the sprintf command in the organizeStyle function.

```
typedef struct{
    int variableOne;
    int variableTwo;
    int variableThree;
    int variableFour;
    double variableFive;
    double variableSix;
} varSet;

void organizeStyle(char *stringout, varSet item){
    sprintf(stringout, "%s %s %s %s %s %s", item.variableOne,item.variableTwo,item.variableThree,item.variableFour,item.variableFive,item.variableSix);
}

int main{
    char putHere[200];
    varSet piece;
    piece.variableOne = 10;
    piece.variableTwo = 15;
    piece.variableThree = 9;
    piece.variableFour = 21;
    piece.variableFive = 3.1;
    piece.variableSix = 7.6;
    organizeStyle(putHere,piece);
    printf("%s",putHere);
    return 0;
}
```

Trying the following did not work:

```
sprintf(stringout, "%s %s %s %s %s %s",(char) item.variableOne,(char) item.variableTwo,(char) item.variableThree,(char) item.variableFour,(char) item.variableFive,(char) item.variableSix);
```

I also tried the following, and it did not work either:

```
sprintf(stringout, "%s %s %s %s %s %s",(char[20]) item.variableOne,(char[20]) item.variableTwo,(char[20]) item.variableThree,(char[20]) item.variableFour,(char[20]) item.variableFive,(char[20]) item.variableSix);
```

I sincerely apologize if this is too simple of a question, I just can't seem to find the appropriate documentation for it online. Also, yes I know I am way over-declaring the size of these strings, I plan to shrink them later when it is all settled & done. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Use `%d` for `int` and `%f` for `double`, instead of `%s`.

Comment: Hint: the (s)printf type specifier is not about what you want to display, but about the type of the parameter which is passed to the function. Also, I'm sort of curious how you are not able to find documentation for this. Googling for "sprintf" returns plenty of relevant results (like this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: @SirDarius What ended up happening is that I tried those %d & %f's first, didn't work, changed it to %s, messed with it for 3 hours wondering why I can't find documentation for ints going into %s, and changed a crap ton of code. When I just put the %d's and %f's back in just now, it worked. I guess I must've fixed whatever I did wrong the first time that made it not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
sprintf(stringout, "%d %d %d %d %f %f", item.variableOne,item.variableTwo,item.variableThree,item.variableFour,item.variableFive,item.variableSix);
```

are the correct format specifier. `%d` for `int` and `%f` for `double`, instead of `%s`.

https://godbolt.org/z/fvTGPvcdq

You should use more compiler flags ( `-Wall` at the minimum for gcc and clang for example) to get warnings about format specifier.

https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf is the documentation for the format specifier, I google for `man printf` when I need to look something up.

Comment: Oh gosh I feel so stupid haha. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use `snprintf()` instead of `sprintf()` to avoid unintentional buffer-overflows.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int vOne;
    int vTwo;
    int vThree;
    int vFour;
    double vFive;
    double vSix;
} varSet;

void organizeStyle (char *stringout, int str_sz, varSet item) {
    snprintf (stringout, str_sz, "%d %d %d %d %lf %lf",
              item.vOne, item.vTwo, item.vThree, item.vFour, item.vFive, item.vSix);
}

int main () {
    char putHere[200];
    varSet piece;
    
    piece.vOne = 10;
    piece.vTwo = 15;
    piece.vThree = 9;
    piece.vFour = 21;
    piece.vFive = 3.1;
    piece.vSix = 7.6;
    organizeStyle (putHere, sizeof (putHere), piece);
    printf ("%s\n", putHere);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Checkout the list of : [Format Specifiers](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

It's better to send base address of the structure:

```
organizeStyle (putHere, sizeof (putHere), &piece);

...
// and function would be
void organizeStyle (char *stringout, int str_sz, varSet* item) {
    snprintf (stringout, str_sz, "%d %d %d %d %lf %lf",
              item->vOne, item->vTwo, item->vThree, item->vFour, item->vFive, item->vSix);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is really helpful, I wish my account had enough reputation to upvote ;-;